# Google Script document openbyid permission error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

If in the onOpen function of a Google Doc I create a spreadsheet object by opening a spreadsheet by id, how can I pass that object to other functions if I'm using the menu system? (longer explanation below)

I have a google doc script that will take a snapshot of a document at a particular time and then export that to .docx and update a spreadsheet with the url of the snapshot. This is initiated by a menu option like so:

```
function onOpen(e) {
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Senate Secretary Menu')
   .addItem('Snapshot', 'snapshot')
  .addToUi();
}
```

Which calls the function snapshot()

```
function snapshot() {
//open the spreadsheet using id
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet_id');
```

This generates a `you do not have permission to call openbyid()` error

I understand that google script prohibits openbyid() from being called in custom functions (which I interpreted as functions in spreadsheet, but whatevs).
if I change the onOpen function to include the OpenById() call it will work.

```
function onOpen(e) {
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Senate Secretary Menu')
   .addItem('Snapshot', 'snapshot')
  .addToUi();
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet_id');
}
```

My question is how can I pass the file object from the onOpen function to the snapshot function?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using the actual spreadsheet ID (a long sequence of letters and numbers) or the string `'spreadsheet_id'`?

Comment: it is actually a long string of numbers. But I found the error posted below.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might also have this problem. I took the menu template from the Google Quickstart, but it has `@OnlyCurrentDoc` flag in the header comment block that I missed. Took that out and my problem was solved.