# google script error "You do not have permission to call create (line 38, file "macros")"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

```
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
```

I am running a Google Sheet script and I get the following error message on the above line of code. Any idea how to solve the issue? I am a novice.

Error message:

> You do not have permission to call create (line 38, file "macros")

Comment: You probably need to grant it permission to run a script the first time you try it. Did you get a popup asking you to approve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAS "You do not have permission to call openById"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587331/gas-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-openbyid)

Comment: @e__n I've already granted this permission. This is not the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably running in a script project that is scoped to only the current document. You can check your current requested scopes in the menu, via `File -> project properties -> Scopes`. Check this list for one like `spreadsheets.currentonly`.

If one like it is there, you have either directly or indirectly specified `// @OnlyCurrentDoc` in your code files (including imported Apps Script libraries).

If this is from a library inclusion, then either add `// @NotOnlyCurrentDoc` in your code (usually positioned at the start of your first `.gs` file) or edit your manifest file to manually specify the desired scopes. If it is from your own code specifying `//@OnlyCurrentDoc`, then just remove this comment.

Scripts which scope to only the current document will generally not trigger the aggressive "Unverified App" authentication flow in which you and/or other document editors must first select "Advanced -> proceed anyway" to approve the script.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50458893
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757366