# How to open several spreadsheet without using openById or openByUrl

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In order to automate calculation on a spreadsheet, i wrote an Apps Script function. I need data from other spreadsheets of my Google Drive, so I tried to use the `openById` and `openByUrl` function.

However, I get a permission error. I read that this function is not available anymore. So how to read data from an other Spreadsheet which is not the active spreadsheet?

Comment: If you're using an inbound script you can't open other spreadsheets from your code. To accomplish this task you will need to create a standalone apps script and connect to your sheets from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google script error "You do not have permission to call create (line 38, file "macros")"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859119/google-script-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-create-line-38-file-m)

Comment: Can you clarify how you are calling the function, are you entering it a spreadsheet cell like =YourCustomFuction() or are you executing it in another way?